# java regular expression Extraction

Tags: java, regex

I have string which has reapeating pipe symbols.

```
String Maindata="1370491695866|223|0|statement| select max(IF_ID) from IF_OPERATIONS.IF_Mediator|select max(IF_ID) from IF_OPERATIONS.IF_Mediator";
```

I need to extract the last part of the String ie.

from the last "|" symbol upto the ";" semicolon(including ";"). So it will be

> select max(IF_ID) from IF_OPERATIONS.IF_Mediator;

I tried but since the "|" symbol is repeating i am getting only

> 223|0|statement| select max(IF_ID) from IF_OPERATIONS.IF_Mediator|select max(IF_ID) from IF_OPERATIONS.IF_Mediator

```
Pattern.compile("\\|([^;]*)").matcher(Maindata);
```

I need the semicolon also to be present. 
It will be a great help if anyone knows this.

Comment: Why don you try String.lastIndexOf("|")
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29

and then take a substring from that index till the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need regular expressions, it is not a miracle solution:

```
String mainData = "1370491695866|223|0|statement| select max(IF_ID) from IF_OPERATIONS.IF_Mediator|select max(IF_ID) from IF_OPERATIONS.IF_Mediator;";
String last = mainData.substring(mainData.lastIndexOf('|') + 1);
System.out.println(last);
```

Result:

```
run:
select max(IF_ID) from IF_OPERATIONS.IF_Mediator;
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

If you might need the other tokens, you also have the `split()` method:

```
String[] tokens = mainData.split("\\|");
System.out.println(tokens[tokens.length - 1]);
```

The `|` is escaped because it has a special signification in regular expressions, and that's what `split()` uses, so is `\` which is also escaped, hence `\\|`.

Comment: Thank you very much but I need to validate this input (as the structure may change but) that is why i used regex. This input may change also.So i thought regex will be a good solution.

Comment: I wrote a regex for validation [0-9]+\\|+[0-9]+\\|+[0]+\\|+[a-z]+\\|+[A-Za-z_.( )]+\\|+[A-Za-z_.( )]+\\; and thanks afor you help